# Codeigniter Datamapper -- Creating new objects and not freeing memory

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using Datamapper to basically sync a bunch of raw data in one database to a more normalized database. I have already set up two sets of Models, one for each database, both extending DM. The issue I am running into is that I need to import gigs worth of data into the new database and when I am creating new DM objects in my controller, they seem to not be freed upon return of whatever method is creating it. The Models do not autoload relationships.

```
$clients = $this->client->get_iterated();
foreach($clients as $client) {
  $this->addUser($client);
}
```

and in addUser() it creates a new User object, saves it and returns. When I output the memory usage of this it just increases until it exhausts everything. At first I thought it was because PHP was creating a copy of the $client object being passed to addUser() but simply putting a 'return' as the first line of addUser() show no increase in memory. It's only when I create the new User object and save it.

I've tried using $user->clear() before the end of the method to no avail.

Worth noting that the application was originally running on the raw database models just fine. The new models are created, saved, and then never freed. This will literally chew through 2 gigs of memory in a few minutes.

Comment: Have you checked that the $user object does not reference any other objects? You need to unset all references to other objects before the garbage collector will free it. There is an open PHP bug concerning this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I too have had this problem and spent many hours of debugging.  The only way around it we found was to resort to using a singleton instance in your model for operations creating many instances, such as:

```
static function get_utility_instance() {
    if ( !self::$utility_instance ) {
        self::$utility_instance = new User_model() ;
    }
    self::$utility_instance->clear() ;
    return self::$utility_instance ;
}
```